# Kill a Forked Child

Tags: c, fork

I am calling fork to create a new process. How can I kill it from the father process?

Comment: You murderer! You are **[The Unforgiven](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYUMPKFYd6g&feature=BFa&list=PLF3C34175C1A85915&lf=plpp_video)**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/kill.html).

The pid is returned to the parent from [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/fork.htmlk).